# How can my boss know that I am looking for a job via LinkedIn?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, linkedin

Today, when my boss was talking with me, he suddenly said: No you don't need to worry about it, everyday you have 3 or 4 messages with agent in LinkedIn, right?

I am very very surprised because :

1. I work at home
2. I don't use VPN
3. I use Linux (Ubuntu) system which installed by me
4. I login with my Chrome / Gmail account
5. I use my personal outlook
6. Every time I talk with the interviewers, I use my Zoom account.
7. I use my own mobile phone, and my sim card.

The only thing is I use a laptop, provided by my company, daily. But as a 15-year IT engineer, I cannot see how it is possible for my company to view my data. Especially, when he knows there are 3 or 4 people I'm talking with everyday.

The only possibility:  is it possible that LinkedIn provides a service that would send my data to my company?

Comment: Do you connect to Linkedin on your company provided laptop?

Comment: I installed Chrome, and I use my gmail account, and I visit linkedin use Chrome only. Of course, I don't have password for login with my Chrome @sf02

Comment: The question as to how your boss might or might not know is off-topic for the Workplace. It could possibly be asked on [Information Security, but please read their on-topic page first](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). How to handle the situation now your boss knows would be on-topic here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an information security question, not one about how to navigate the workplace.

Comment: You probably told someone, and they told him

Comment: Absolutely no possible, I even not talk in Slack, because I know they are monitoring @Kilisi

Comment: You don't tell your friends or family?

Comment: Sure, I even not tell my wife about finding a new job, the only possible is, the Head hunter tell my boss, I am now thinking about this possibility @Kilisi

Comment: yeah, someone told him, it's more likely to be a social engineering issue than a technical one. Recruiters aren't always honest either.

Comment: If an head hunter told him, then it is very scare! Then no one dare to find a job in this social!

Comment: `he suddenly said: No you don't need to worry about it` Worry about what? How does getting contacted on LinkedIn factor into the conversation you were having? The context could be important to the answers you get here.

Comment: We are talking about ppl which need to be "improve performance", and I am in the list. And he mentioned about that. They(including my HR) already book a meeting to me tomorrow. Yes, we all know what is going to happen. @SethR

Comment: If he "created a fake account and send me a message", then he wins, I have no complained! really!

Comment: @Elisa, Did you just write in this comment section that you are on the PIP (Performance Improvement Plan) ? Many people in this forum have commented that they rarely see any worker survive a PIP in the long run, unfortunately...  So, I would suggest that you continue the job search regardless of what your boss knows or guesses about your LinkedIn activity. Good luck.

Comment: @Elisa, so how'd it go?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest explanation is your boss is assuming this because it happens to so many people. There are even threads on this site complaining about excess contact with recruiters. That said, perhaps your activity on LI is apparent; people can see sudden rebuilding of your profile, or you following new companies. Also, people in various companies talk to each other. It's likely not a fancy surveillance issue.

Comment: You mean that, it has possibility that some people working in the company I am interviewing, told my boss?

Comment: But the thing is, my boss know every day 3 to 4 agent is finding me in Linkedin!! I am very very suprised

Comment: 3-4 sounds like a guess based on common knowledge. Your boss or coworkers could be getting the same rate of hits. And yes, perhaps someone at a company you are applying to, perhaps a hiring manager, knows your boss or used to work at your company. We can't know.

Comment: @Elisa, Turn it around. Say, "yes, I'm getting those calls like everyone is. But, I'm not interested."

Comment: Well, sadly to tell you that I am in a very bad position and context now, no chance to say back. HR already book a meeting to me tomorrow :) @DavidR

Comment: I agree. Perhaps it was a coincident that he said exactly what you were doing based upon his own personal experience. Also if he knows you have a linkedin account, perhaps using common sense he just said what he said.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't even a hard topic. Engineering positions are abundant right now. In the current market, any engineer with a LinkedIn profile that demonstrates even a cursory understanding of a specific discipline will be getting 3-5 attempts to connect on a daily basis.

Your manager likely doesn't know you're responding to those recruiter requests, and still it's not hard to know you're getting them. Most likely they're trying to gauge you're interest and likelihood for retention. I have a number of very talented people on my team, and I know they're getting LinkedIn-bombed on a daily basis. It's a fight I continually have to have with executives to make sure I can continue to offer a competitive wage and continue pursuing product choices that they find interesting and compelling. (luckily, I work for an executive team that is very plugged into this concept and works with me every step of the way)

LinkedIn actually offers the opposite service in which they will not show data to your company if you are returned in a search set. It is possible that they're using a non-company affiliated account to search for individuals who have marked themselves as "Open to work". The more likely scenario is that your manager is just aware of the reality and trying to get you to "confess" to looking.

Answer (score 5):

The only good answer to a remark like this is to say:

> What? You only get 3 or 4 a day! I get at least 10 a day.

After all, he's only saying 3 or 4 a day probably because he's also getting 3 or 4 messages on LinkedIn a day. So it's only right that you tease him back by saying that you're getting way more than him.

Besides, even if you're wrong, what is going to say? "No, I know you wrote back to a recruiter this morning. The malware I installed on your laptop twelve months ago tells me everything you do on it."

Answer (score 1):

Everyone in the industry with an ounce of credibility and a presence on linkedin will receive messages from recruiters. They may have simply meant *of course* you receive messages on linked in from recruiters, in the same way that *of course* water is wet.

I wonder about the context of it being raised by your manager during a work conversation, but I think your boss was simply assuming that you're a skilled engineer, with an account on LinkedIn, which means you are receiving messages from recruiters.

Comment: The context is happen after they told me will fire me. So I believe my boss is not have any assumption, but I was betrayed by a headhunter